# Jupyter notebook extensions tab not showing up using poetry as dependency manager

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-poetry

I am using poetry as my dependency manager and the extensions tab is not showing up when I launch jupyter notebooks. How do I get the tab to show up?

My `pyproject.toml` has these dependencies

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.8,<3.11"
ipython = "^8.10.0"
jupyter = "^1.0.0"
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions = "^0.7.0"
```

And I ran

```
poetry run jupyter contrib nbextension install --user 
poetry run jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
poetry run jupyter notebook
```

But there's no extensions tab:
[screenshot of jupyter notebook UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuEXa.png).

The poetry-installed `jupyter notebook` version is 6.5.2 and my `poetry` version is 1.2.2.

As an aside, I'm also wondering how to add extensions from the command line. I know the command is `poetry run jupyter nbextension enable <nbextension>` but, in general, where can I find the `<nbextension>`? E.g., for "Snippets Menu", what's the `<nbextension>`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the current `notebook==6.5.2`.

https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1628

Your options are either to wait for the fix (seems the team is working on it), or to install an earlier version of `notebook`. To do this within poetry, run:

`poetry run pip install notebook==6.4.8`

And `poetry run jupyter notebook` should give you the Nbextensions tab.

Note using pip within poetry is generally discouraged - consider this a temporary workaround...